# how to display all students doing each course

Tags: c++

I am trying to display the number of students doing each course, but it firstly gives me the right amount when i enter the first course , but when i enter the second course it adds all courses.
the main issue is on case 6: id really appreciate your help. I'm sort of a beginner in programming.
here's the part of code below:

```
     #include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string>
#include<iomanip>
#include<fstream>
#include<cstring> 
#include<vector>
#include<assert.h>

using namespace std;

struct student
{
    char name[80];
    char sname[80];

    int idno;
    char cours[100];
    int age;
    int modules;
};

int main()
{
    ofstream cfile;
    ofstream sfile;
    char dow;
    int arr=0;
    do{

        student stud[100];

        cout<<"Press 1 Enter record \n";
        cout<<"Press 2 Delete record \n";
        cout<<"Press 3 Update record \n";
        cout<<"Press 4 Search record \n";
        cout<<"Press 5 To check number of students doing each course \n";
        cout<<"Press 6 To check student course file \n";
        cout<<"Press 7 Display record \n";
        cout<<"\n\t Select option::";

        int idcheck=0;

        int sw;
        cin>>sw;

        switch(sw)
        {

             case 1:

                cout<<"\n Enter the data of the student no "<<arr+1<<" is :\n";

                cout<<"\t Enter the Roll No = ";
                int id2;
                int id;

                cin>>id;

                for(int j=0; j<=arr; j++)
                {

                    id2=id;
                    if(id2==stud[j].idno)
                    {
                        idcheck=1;
                     }
                 }
                 if(idcheck!=1){
                    stud[arr].idno=id;

                    cout<<"\t Enter the Name = ";
                    cin>>stud[arr].name;

                    cout<<"\t Enter the Surname = ";
                    cin>>stud[arr].sname;

                    cout<<"\t Enter the age = ";
                    cin>>stud[arr].age;

                    cout<<"\t Enter the Course = ";
                    cin>>stud[arr].cours;

                    cout<<"\t Enter the Modules = ";
                    cin>>stud[arr].modules;

                    arr=arr+1;
                 }
                 else
                 {
                    cout<<"This Record is Already Entered \n"; 
                 }

                 break;


                 case 2:

                    cout<<"\n Enter the Roll no of the student To Delete :: \n";

                    cin>>id;

                    for(int j=0; j<=arr; j++)
                    {
                        id2=id;
                        if(id2==stud[j].idno)
                        {

                            stud[j].idno='d';
                            cout<<"\t Record Deleted";

                         }
                     }

                     break;

                     case 3:
                        cout<<"\n Enter the Roll no of the student To Update ::\n";

                        cin>>id;

                        for(int j=0; j<=arr; j++)
                        {

                            id2=id;
                            if(id2==stud[j].idno)
                            {
                                cout<<"\t ID = ";
                                cout<<stud[j].idno;

                                cout<<"\t Name = ";
                                cout<<stud[j].name;

                                cout<<"\t Surname = ";
                                cout<<stud[j].sname;

                                cout<<"\t Age = ";
                                cout<<stud[j].age;

                                cout<<"\t Course = ";
                                cout<<stud[j].cours;

                                cout<<"\t Modules = ";
                                cout<<stud[j].modules;



                                cout<<"\n\t Re-Enter Data ";

                                cout<<"\n\t Enter the Name = ";
                                cin>>stud[j].name;

                                cout<<"\n\t Enter the Surname = ";
                                cin>>stud[j].sname;

                                cout<<"\n\t Enter the Age = ";
                                cin>>stud[j].age;

                                cout<<"\n\t Enter the Course = ";
                                cin>>stud[j].cours;

                                cout<<"\n\t Enter the Modules = ";
                                cin>>stud[j].modules;


                             }
                         }

            break;  

            case 4:

            cout<<"\n Enter the ID number of the student To Search ::"; 

            cin>>id;

            for(int j=0; j<=arr; j++)
            {
                id2=id; 
                if(id2==stud[j].idno)
                {
                    cout<<"\n\t ID = ";
                    cout<<stud[j].idno;

                    cout<<"\n\t Name = ";
                    cout<<stud[j].name;

                    cout<<"\n\t Surname = ";
                    cout<<stud[j].sname;

                    cout<<"\n\t Age = ";
                    cout<<stud[j].age;

                    cout<<"\n\t Course = ";
                    cout<<stud[j].cours;

                    cout<<"\n\t Modules = ";
                    cout<<stud[j].modules;

                }
            }

            break;

            case 5:
                {

                    string  str;
                    int i, count = 0;

                    cout<<"Enter Course: ";
                    cin>>str;




         for( i=0; i<=str.size(); i++)
         {
            if(str == stud[i].cours)

         {
            count++;
         }
    }
                     cout<<"Number of students doing "<<str<<" are "<<count;
                    }

            break;

            case 6:
                {
                    string str;
                    int n, count = 0;

                cout<<"Enter number of courses: ";
                cin>>n;

            for(int i=0; i<=n-1; i++)
                    {
                    cout<<"Enter course: ";

                cin>>str;


         for(int i=0; i<=str.size(); i++)   

         {      

        if(str == stud[i].cours)

         {
count++;

}

}

    cout<<"Number of students doing "<<str<<" are "<<count<<endl;


}

}
                cout<<"\n__________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________"<<endl;
                for(int i=0; i<1; i++)
                {
                    cout<<setw(12)<<"Rollno ||";
                    cout<<setw(12)<<" Name   ||";
                    cout<<setw(12)<<" Surname    || ";
                    cout<<setw(12)<<"Age  ||";
                      cout<<setw(12)<<" Course  ||";
                      cout<<setw(12)<<" Module   ||";

                      for(int k=0; k<arr; k++)
                      {
                        if(stud[k].idno!='d')
                        {
                            cout<<"\n";
                            cout<<" ";
                            cout<<setw(5)<<stud[k].idno;

                            cout<<setw(15)<<stud[k].name;

                        cout<<setw(14)<<stud[k].sname;

                         cout<<setw(14)<<stud[k].age;

                          cout<<setw(12)<<stud[k].cours;

                            cout<<setw(14)<<stud[k].modules;

                            }
                        }
                }
                cout<<"\n______________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________"<<endl;



                    {

                        cfile.open("CourseFile.txt");

                    string  str;
                    int i,count = 0;

            for(i=0; i<2; i++)
    {

         for( i=0; i<=sizeof(str); i++)
         {
            if(str == stud[i].cours)

         {
            count++;
         }
    }


                     cfile<<"Number of students doing "<<str<<" are "<<count;
                    }
            }








            cfile<<"\n__________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________"<<endl;
                for(int i=0; i<1; i++)
                {
                    cfile<<setw(12)<<"Rollno ||";
                    cfile<<setw(12)<<" Name   ||";
                    cfile<<setw(12)<<" Surname    || ";
                    cfile<<setw(12)<<"Age  ||";
                      cfile<<setw(12)<<" Course  ||";
                      cfile<<setw(12)<<" Module   ||";

                      for(int k=0; k<arr; k++)
                      {
                        if(stud[k].idno!='d')
                        {
                            cfile<<"\n";
                            cfile<<" ";
                            cfile<<setw(5)<<stud[k].idno;

                            cfile<<setw(15)<<stud[k].name;

                        cfile<<setw(14)<<stud[k].sname;

                         cfile<<setw(14)<<stud[k].age;

                          cfile<<setw(12)<<stud[k].cours;

                            cfile<<setw(14)<<stud[k].modules;

                            }
                        }
                }
            cfile<<"\n______________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________"<<endl;

            cfile.close();


                break;

            case 7:
                {

                sfile.open("StudentFile.txt");
                cout<<"\n__________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________";
                for(int i=0; i<1; i++)
                {
                    cout<<setw(12)<<"Rollno ||";
                    cout<<setw(12)<<" Name   ||";
                    cout<<setw(12)<<" Surname    || ";
                    cout<<setw(12)<<"Age  ||";
                      cout<<setw(12)<<" Course  ||";
                      cout<<setw(12)<<" Module   ||";

                      for(int k=0; k<arr; k++)
                      {
                        if(stud[k].idno!='d')
                        {
                            cout<<"\n";
                            cout<<" ";
                            cout<<setw(5)<<stud[k].idno;

                            cout<<setw(15)<<stud[k].name;

                        cout<<setw(14)<<stud[k].sname;

                         cout<<setw(14)<<stud[k].age;

                          cout<<setw(12)<<stud[k].cours;

                            cout<<setw(14)<<stud[k].modules;

                            }
                        }
                }
                cout<<"\n______________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________";



        for(int i=0; i<1; i++)
                {
                    sfile<<setw(12)<<"Rollno ||";
                    sfile<<setw(12)<<" Name   ||";
                    sfile<<setw(12)<<" Surname    || ";
                    sfile<<setw(12)<<"Age  ||";
                      sfile<<setw(12)<<" Course  ||";
                      sfile<<setw(12)<<" Module   ||";

                      for(int k=0; k<arr; k++)
                      {
                        if(stud[k].idno!='d')
                        {
                            sfile<<"\n";
                            sfile<<" ";
                            sfile<<setw(5)<<stud[k].idno;

                            sfile<<setw(15)<<stud[k].name;

                        sfile<<setw(14)<<stud[k].sname;

                         sfile<<setw(14)<<stud[k].age;

                          sfile<<setw(12)<<stud[k].cours;

                            sfile<<setw(14)<<stud[k].modules;

                            sfile.close();

                            }
                        }
                }


            }


                break;

                default:
                    cout<<"\t Wrong option Selected ";
                    break;
        }

    cout<<"\n\n\t Do You Want to Continue Again [Y/N]";
    cin>>dow;

}
while(dow=='y');
return 0;
getch();
}
```

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for some tips on how to debug your code. This is a critical skill to learn as you learn to program. If you still have trouble, come back and [edit] your question with a [mcve] that we can copy and compile and run ourselves.

Comment: great let me check the article asap

Comment: I highly recommend searching the internet before posting.  For example, use the following search terms:  C++ student course number.  You'll find a lot of examples related to your assignment.

Comment: The definition of `stud` is missing from your post.  You should use `std::vector` instead of an array.

Comment: let me try that @Thomas Matthews

Comment: i just added the full program @Thomas Matthews. i haven't used vectors before

Comment: Hint: What is the value of count _after_ you are done with course A? What should that value be _before_ course B starts?

Comment: the value of count should be zero again

Comment: i tried those methods in the article there isn't any issue @Code-Apprentice

Comment: @Rietty i tried to update the count after every course input, however nothing happens.unless i'm implementing it badly.

Comment: @user210580 What do you mean "there isn't an issue"?

Comment: well i tried all debugging methods and none showed any error besides the part for displaying the number of students in each course @Code-Apprentice

Comment: @young- The discrepancy in the number of students in each course is what you are trying to solve, right? That is what debugging techniques will help you do.

Comment: well that is what am trying to solve. but seeingly im doing the debugging in a wrong way idk. maybe you can help me debug